# Помогите с разделением строки, пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x

На входе имеем строки типа `'cd c://'` или `'dir/?>1.txt'`. На выходе надо получить список из 2х строк. `['cd', ' c://']` или `['dir', '/?>1.txt']`.
То-есть все буквы что идут подряд с начала строки в `list[0]` + все остальное в том числе пробелы в `list[1]`. Понимаю что надо использовать re. Но не могу понять как именно. Спасибо.

`re.split(r'[^a-zA-Z]', my_string, maxsplit=1)` - работает, но обрезает первую не букву. А мне она нужна.

Таакс...`re.split(r'([^a-zA-Z])', my_string, maxsplit=1)` уже сохраняет разделитель но в отдельный элемент списка...

Еще ближе `re.split(r'(^\w+)', 'abcxde$/$fxghi')` делает

```
`['', 'abcxde', '$/$fxghi']`
```

Осталось обрезать пустой 1 элемент. Но мы резать не будем, а еще покрутим регулярное выражение чтобы его и не добавляло... Решение близко.

Comment: Хотя пробелы, наверное, не обязательно. Короче говоря мне нужно выделить команду из строки и отдельно все остальные параметры. По первому элементу списка решается какой функции отдаем второй элемент (параметры).

Comment: Можете почитать про метод split, который применяется к строкам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import re

_list = [ 'aaa/aaas', 'aaa(aaad', 'aaaa^$aaaf', 'aaa%4aa', 'aaa aaaw']

pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
for line in _list:
    print(pattern.search(line).group())
```

---

**Update**

```
import re
_list = [ 'aaa/aaas', 'aaa(aaad', 'aaaa^$aaaf', 'aaa%4aa', 'aaa aaaw']

pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')

for line in _list:
    p = pattern.search(line).group()
    l = [p, line[len(p):]]
    print(l)
```

Comment: Все работает, но мне на выходе надо список ['aaa', '/aaas'] и тд. То есть строки разбитые на все буквы до 1 не буквы и все что дальше включая 1 не букву. А не только 1 часть.

Comment: @Keymaster я добавил обновление

Answer (score 0):

Для первого случая:

```
my_str = "cd c://"
my_list = my_str.split(" ")
print(my_list)
```

Если нужны дальнейшие пробелы то так:

```
my_list = my_str.split(" ", maxsplit=1)
```

Для второго случая:

```
my_str = 'dir/?>1.txt'
my_list = my_str.split("/")
my_list[1] = "/" + my_list[1]
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Дело в том что нужен 1 способ для всех случаев. Так как на вход может подаваться что угодно, а выделить надо все буквы с начала и до 1 небуквы. А дальше уже пусть функция которой передано все что послее ее имени разбирается что с этим делать.

Comment: @Keymaster приведите пример какие случаи могут быть и что из этого нужно выделить

Comment: 'aaa/aaa', 'aaa(aaa', 'aaaa^$aaa', 'aaa%4aa'a, 'aaa aaa'. А выделить нужно строку до 1 небуквы + все что после (включаяя первую не букву.)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import re

str = "cd /tmp"
m = re.match(r'^(\w+)(.*)$',str);
print(m.group(1))
print(m.group(2))
```